# How do I run a js function and change html page?

Tags: javascript, html

tl;dr - Is it possible to have a submit button run a function and change from it's current HTML page to another while using the result of the function on the page it switches to?

Currently I have it running a function but now I have a second function added to the js file. To display the result I want to change HTML page.

This is the current form I have atm:

```
<form onsubmit="return rrr()" method ="POST">
   What room is closest to you: <input id="from" type="text">
   <br>
   <br>
    What room do you want to go to : <input id="to" type="text">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

That works fine at the moment. Want I'm trying to do is, when I press submit, it runs the rrr() function and change to another HTML page where I can run the other function which is where the result for the functions will be displayed.

Comment: Can you show your js function what have done?

Answer (score 3):

```
function rrr(){
    window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask'
}
```

Comment: Should it not be in the HTML file and not the function? The function only does dijkstras algorithm for me. I was hoping to use the result of dijkstras on another HTML page and display the results there. The other function I have displays whatever results are in the array I'm trying to send over. It works with hard coded results but I don't know how to send the dijkstras result over.